# Can't resolve indirect interface

Tags: idris

I'm having difficulty with indirect interface resolution. I have a set of backend (custom C++) types (e.g. `float64`) that I capture in Idris with empty types (e.g. `F64`), and which correspond to Idris builtin types (e.g. `Double`). I capture the ability to read and write from the backend with an interface

```
interface BackendRW cpp idr where
```

For example, I have the implementation

```
BackendRW F64 Double where
```

I use this interface to constrain operations on backend types by properties on the Idris types. For example

```
negate : (Neg idr, BackendRW cpp idr) => cpp -> cpp
```

But at usage site I'm finding Idris can't resolve `?idr` in `negate` in

```
x : F64

y : F64
y = -x
```

There are no other implementations for `F64` than that shown above. I get

> Can't find an implementation for (Neg ?idr, BackendRW F64 ?idr)

It works if I specify `{idr=Double}` but that's not practical. I tried to fix this by saying each C++ type corresponds to only one Idris type and using a determining parameter

```
interface BackendRW cpp idr | cpp where
```

but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I can use

```
interface BackendRW cpp idr | cpp where
```

if I don't ask for both implementations at once

```
negate : Neg idr => BackendRW cpp idr => cpp -> cpp
```

which presumably means the type checker is freer to find one implementation then the other rather than both at the same time.